# c# mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql

hello i have 1 problem with the execute .

```
string MyConString = "SERVER=<snip>;" + "DATABASE=<snip>;" + "UID=<snip>;" + "PASSWORD=<snip>;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "UPDATE characters SET nobless=1 WHERE char_name=";

connection.Open();
try
{
    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
MessageBox.Show("Done");
connection.Close();

command.CommandText = "UPDATE characters SET nobless=1 WHERE char_name=";
```

i want:

```
WHERE char_name = textbox1.text
```

for example, how can i do it?
for example if i make it:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE characters SET nobless=1 WHERE char_name='hello'";
```

it works.

but when i have it:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE characters SET nobless=1 WHERE char_name="+listbox1.selecteditem.toString();
```

it does not work, actually i want to set as `WHERE =` the selected name of one list box!

Comment: You need to be more clear about what "Doesn't work" means here. Is there an error? Also, that code has a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: Also, the problem is that you don't have quotes around the value in your concatenated string, but use a parameterized query like Oded suggests else your site is very hackable.

Comment: You need to use listbox1.SelectedVALUE or listbox1.selectedItem.TEXT. You can cast those ToString() if they aren't aleady strings.

Comment: Look, I suggest you use Oded's response because you want to use parameterized queries. But the code you're looking for is command.CommandText = "UPDATE characters SET nobless=1 WHERE char_name='" + listbox1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";

Answer (score 1):

Use a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html):

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE characters SET nobless=1 WHERE char_name= @char_name"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@char_name", listbox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: no errors but it doesn't work. actually i don't know how to add a text  variable in here:

Comment: where char_name=textbox.1text

Comment: i want to do it something like this, but how?

Comment: @user1174925 - I have given you all the help I can. The code should replace your line of code.